# How do I get my UIWebView to automatically fit content like a WKWebView does?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiwebview, wkwebview

I was comparing a UIWebView and a WKWebView to see which would be best to display PDF content. I realized that WKWebView's automatically scale the content to fit the screen with no code needed, like so:

[[image]]  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLYIq.png)[[image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYkT8.png)

While no matter what code I tried implementing in my UIWebView, the content just won't fit like the WKWebView does, here's what it looks like in my UIWebView:

[image][image]

```
and here is the code for my webView:

class WebView: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var myWebView: UIWebView!


    var contentUrlPassedOn: String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        myWebView.delegate = self

        let url: NSURL! = NSURL(string: contentUrlPassedOn)
        myWebView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url))

        self.myWebView.scalesPageToFit = true
        myWebView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
        myWebView.frame = self.view.frame
        myWebView.scrollView.bouncesZoom = true

    }
```

How can I get my UIWebView to fit content like the WKWebView?

Answer (score 0):

This is in Objective-C, but this is how I do it.  If you translate it will work just fine.

```
[self.webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
```

Perhaps, also removing this line would help do the trick.  Not sure you really need it:

```
myWebView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
```

Another idea is that you should set auto layout constraints to pin your UIWebView to the top and sides so that it won't resize to larger than the screen size.

Here is an example of how I would do this in Objective-C:

```
NSURLRequest*request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[self.webView loadRequest:request];

[self.webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];

self.webView.delegate = self;
```

Comment: i already that line in my viewDidLoad and it wouldn't work, but my webView has constraints pinning it to all sides of the view

Comment: Did you try removing the line that I suggested, also remove the line that sets the frame property of the UIWebView.  Not sure if this would have any effect, but I am setting my delegate=self aft calling setScalesPageToFit.  What iOS version are you testing on, that might could have an effect.

Comment: Actually, what could be happening is that calling loadRequest could be taking longer than expected and scalesPageToFit is called before your UIWebView has its content.  Just another idea to check out...

Comment: testing on 8.4 and I moved the scalesPageToFit in my progress bar code, so after the progress bar is finished loading, ` scalesPageToFit`, but no success. pretty odd

Comment: I updated my answer as to how I do this in Objective-C.  This code works exactly how you would like, so the problem is most likely coming from somewhere else.

Comment: yes i've those lines implement for a while now, no dice. I'm guessing the problem lies somewhere else